# How can I get rid of items that can't be phased to their 'box' form in the pattern buffer (queue of items that can be 'phased')?

Tags: startopia

I have items in my pattern buffer (queue of items that can be 'phased' by left clicking on them) that when placed, doesn't turn into its box form, e.g. litter bins (which will immediately transform into a litter bin, and not in a box form), or dispensers, which can only be placed inside a medical bay.

This means that I can't place the box in the Cargo Bay or another area where I can easily organize the boxes. This also causes the pattern buffer queue to fill up with these items.  How do I remove these items in the pattern buffer (aside from placing them down) or turn these items into 'box' form?

This is the only info regarding the pattern buffer's controls that I can find in the game manual:

> Certain items can be picked and placed within the station’s Pattern Buffer. To place an item in the Pattern Buffer left click on the item. An icon will appear in the Pattern
>   Buffer representing that item. To retrieve an item from the Pattern Buffer left click on any empty area within your station (this will place the newest item in your buffer on the
>   deck) or left click and hold on one of the icons in the buffer and drag it to an empty area.

Screenshot of the pattern buffer filled with items that I can't remove from it (encircled in red):
*The 'chair' icon is the Dispenser and the blue box icon is the Litter Bin.*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got an item that you wish to re-box, I believe you can do so by deploying it within a room and then repacking the entire room (this boxes the room and all it's furniture, separately). This does require placing the item down first, but once boxed they could be placed in to cargo holds as desired.

Obviously some things cannot be (re)boxed, and this won't help you with them.

If you don't have the time for this faffing about (or it's an unboxable item) and you need to clear the buffer, you could just drop the items in to a Recycler, obviously at the cost of losing the item in exchange for some energy.

Comment: The other way of getting rid of stuff is to drop it over an open stardock. The recycler is better since it returns energy, but if you are overrun with litter and have a stardock but no recycler, dumping litter into space can keep the rats down. You can also drop stuff on an analyzer. Although a slow way to use up stuff, this has the advantage of lowering your manufacturing costs for that item.